# show refreshing icon on ios app

Tags: ios, refresh

how to change refresh button to a refreshing icon? Like when the app is updating, there is a pop up windows in the center of app with animated refreshing icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking for a modal activity indicator. The one that people most commonly use is [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD).

[image: MBProgressHUD sample image]